# font-size always larger than custom setting on mobile

Tags: css, font-size

Do anyone know how the css work on mobile? I tried to declare any statement below one by one but no luck.

```
@font-size-base: 20px;
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Refer to the image I attached, the font-size was redeclared 2 times from html {10px} to  body {16px} and then to p {16px}, but finally it was changed to 28.8px, it is very large on mobile.

In the head, I do declare the meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I can't find which statement change the font-size to 28.8px.  Please help.

Comment: is it online if we want to test it or somewhere like jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, you can visit http://viewwinliberal.com.hk/tour/t608/ as most of the content are in Traditional Chinese, you can search the content "SHATEC School for Hospitality & Tourism in Singapore"

I added the style
@media (min-width: 320px)
p {
    font-size: calc( 10px );
}

to fix the font-size but you still have find the problem if I don't redeclare the font-size with calc(), the problem font-size is 28.8px